# Как по нажатию на TextView получить индекс символа?

Tags: android, textview

Есть TextView. В нем есть некий текст. Программа должна возвращать индекс символа после нажатия на TextView. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Индекс какого символа, на котором стоит курсор или что? Уточните вопрос

Comment: Да, иднекс символа, на который нажал юзер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Повесьте слушатель касаний на `TextView`, отловите отпускание пальца, берите линию через `y` и символ как `x`. В `Toast` выведется индекс буквы. Но я в этом способе не уверен, проверьте

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
  Layout layout = ((TextView) v).getLayout();
  int x = (int)event.getX();
  int y = (int)event.getY();
  if (layout!=null){
      int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
      int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
      Toast.makeText(context, "" + offset, 1).show();
      }
}
return true;
}
});
```